# How to redirect a printer from Windows to Ubuntu server from an external network?

Tags: networking, printing, samba, remote-desktop

I want to switch from Windows Server to Ubuntu server (to connect users from external network via RDP). Most of the tasks have been done, but the last problem is that the client when connecting via RDP needs to redirect its printer, to Ubuntu desktop. I have read all the possible forums, but I have not found an answer. The standard RDP does not redirect the printer. On Ubuntu, the best I could do was to forward it through smb (but from the same network as Ubuntu server). The issue of publishing the printer through the client router is also not suitable (because not everyone has statics). Maybe there is some xrdp analog that can see the client printer?

Comment: CUPS is the generic printer system for Linux. It has a browser config (localhost:631) and can do all you want: all you needs if for all printers to be connected to the network.

Comment: Rinzwind. The user is on a different network. CUPS can only redirect the printer from the user's system to the local address. And I need to be able to redirect the printer to the Ubuntu server when I am on an external network.

Comment: @user68186
The user is using Windows and is anywhere in the world. The user connects to my Ubuntu server and I need him to be able to redirect his printer, which is at his home, via xrdp or an analog to the remote Ubuntu server desktop. Regardless of the type of connection, USB, LAN of Wi-fi

Comment: It is best if you put this in your questions. Comments are our channel to ask you for clarifications. They may be deleted later.

Comment: You may find [this q & a in the raspberry pi exchange useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56254792/printing-using-cups-via-internet)

Comment: That is called "cloud printing". @your29

Comment: Solved! I found a way to redirect the printer through the cloud papercut. The host is installed on Windows, from where the link to the desired printer is published. Since papercut is not supported on Ubuntu, you have to install Google Chrome on your system and install the papercut plugin. Then you can use the host link to print from any document on the system to a printer on an external network